# imagecopyresampled in PHP, can someone explain it?

Tags: php, image-manipulation, gd

OK i thought i understood this function but i have a complete mental block on this one.

I wanted to create cropped thumbnails of size 75x75 from photos that are 800x536.

the imagecopyresampled function has 10 possible parameters. i first tried this:

```
// Starting point of crop
        $tlx = floor(($width / 2) - ($new_width / 2)); //finds halfway point of big image and subtracts half of thumb.
        $tly = floor(($height / 2) - ($new_height / 2)); //gets centre of image to be cropped.

imagecopyresampled($tmp_img,$img,0,0,$tlx,$tly,$new_width,$new_height,$orig_width,$orig_height);
```

this finds either side of the halfway mark on the large image and crops it out. or so i thought. but it actuall crops a bit of the picture and leaves the right hand side and bottom in black (presumably from the imagecreatetruecolor earlier.

so i found a way to do what i want but i want you to explain how it is working.

i now have:

```
//Create thumbnails.
            $new_width = 75; //pixels.
            $new_height = 75;

            if($width > $height) $biggest_side = $width;   
            else $biggest_side = $height;   

            //The crop size will be half that of the largest side   
            $crop_percent = .5;   
            $crop_width   = $biggest_side*$crop_percent;   
            $crop_height  = $biggest_side*$crop_percent;

            $c1 = array("x"=>($width-$crop_width)/2, "y"=>($height-$crop_height)/2);

        //Create new image with new dimensions to hold thumb
        $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);

        //Copy and resample original image into new image.
            imagecopyresampled($tmp_img,$img,0,0,$c1['x'],$c1['y'],$new_width,$new_height,$crop_width,$crop_height);
```

it's doing it perfectly, shrinking the image and then cropping out the middle, but my maths isn't very sharp and also i think it's definitely that i don't fully understand the imagecopyresampled function.

can someone walk me through it? parameter by parameter. especially the last two. originally i entered the width and height of the original image, but this enters 400 and 400 (half of the longest side). sorry for the rant. hope my mind understands this soon :)

Alex

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's fairly simple, documented [here](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)

The parameters:

1) $dst_image, a valid GD handle representing the image you want to copy INTO
2) $src_image, a valid GD Handle represending the image you're copying FROM

3) $dst_x - X offset in the destination image you want to place the resampled image into
4) $dst_y - Y offset, ditto

5) $src_x - X offset in the source image you want to start copying from
6) $src_y - Y offset, ditto

7) $dst_x - X width of the newly resampled image in $dst_image
8) $dst_y - Y width, ditto

9) $src_x - X width of the area to copy out of the $src_image
10) $src_y - Y width, ditto

So...

You've got a $src_image that's 800x536, and a $dst_image that's 75x75

```
       $width = 800                                $new_width = 75
+-----------------------+                        +----+
|                       |                        |    |
|                       |                        |    | $new_height = 75
|                       | $height = 536          +----+
|                       |
|                       |
+-----------------------+
```

Sounds like you want to take the middle chunk of the source image and make a thumbnail from that, right? This middle chunk should represent half the height & width of the original image, so you want:

```
$start_X = floor($width / 4); //  200
$width_Y = floor($height / 4); // 134

  200     400      200       
+-----------------------+
|     |          |      | 134
|-----+----------+------|
|     | This part|      | 268
|-----+----------+------|
|     |          |      | 134
+-----------------------+

$end_x = $start_X + (2 * $start_x) // 3 * $start_x = 600
$end_y = $start_Y + (2 * $start_y) // 3 * $start_y = 402

imagecopyresampled($src, $dst, 0, 0, $startX, $start_y, 75, 75, $end_x, $end_y);
                               a  b  c        d         e   f   g       h
```

a,b - start pasting the new image into the top-left of the destination image
c,d - start sucking pixels out of the original image at 200,134
e,f - make the resized image 75x75 (fill up the thumbnail)
g,h - stop copying pixels at 600x402 in the original image

Now, this is assuming that you want the thumbnail to be completely filled up. If you want the source image to be shrunk proportionally (so it has the same ration of height/width as the original, then you'll have to do some math to adjust the `a,b` and `e,f` parameters.

Comment: wow thanks a lot. the drawings make it so much easier to understand! so speedy too. 

so, you're using the end_x and end_y parameters for the stopping coordinates, when the manual ( i have look at this a lot) says it's the width and height of the source image. that is quite different from what uve said. now, what i'm using now, that is working has 400x400 in end_x and end_y. so does that mean it's taking a 400x400 cut out of the center and then shrinking that into 75x75?

Comment: when it says "source image" for the end_x/end_y, it's the end of the PIECE of the source image you want to work with. If you want to shrink the entire image, then it's the height/width of the original image. Otherwise it's just the height/width of the chunk you're slicing out.

Comment: right so im just shrinking a 400 by 400 piece of the entire image and then taking the middle 75x75 square of that? i think i get it. huzzah!

Comment: No, you're copying a 400x268 chunk of the original image, shrinking the copy to 75x75 and pasting that into the destination image, which happens to be 75x75.

Comment: but by making height = biggest_side * crop_percent as well as width, it's 400 by 400. i think by ur way it will be doing that, but looking at my figures its 400x400. if i did your way, urs is a rectangle so it would be squashed into 75x75