# php crop image when i mergecopy two png

Tags: image, transparency, crop

i need some help if is possible, 
i want to combine two image with php, the both is png, and only one is transparency.

my problem is:
when make "imagecopy" i want top crop second image. attached a image to best explain.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZDPR.png)

Code is:

```
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct){ 
$cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h); 
imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct); 
}
$image1 = imagecreatefrompng('images/product/'.$image); //300 x 300
$image2 = imagecreatefromgif('dsgcache/123456.gif'); //150 x 150
$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
imagealphablending($merged_image, false);
imagesavealpha($merged_image, true);
imagecopy($merged_image, $image1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300);
imagecopymerge_alpha($merged_image, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, 50);
header('Content-Type: ' . image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_PNG));
imagepng($merged_image);
```

is possible to make this with gd and php?

thanks.

Comment: yes, just play with the src_whatever variables - they define where in the source image you want to copy from.

Comment: thanks Marc, but i don't understand what you want to say.. :|

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604940/imagecopyresampled-in-php-can-someone-explain-it

Comment: I tried the link but it is still not working, try .. :)

Comment: i update and image to exact show what i want to make. thanks

Comment: i done, i use imagewide and my problem is solved :)